# How to display data after a specific condition MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

we have a table which contains all the programs and levels that the students have been assigned to.
this table called '**tbl_assignedclass**' contains studentID, programID, levelID and semesterID

i need to display student's statistics after he finish three semesters with the same program and level, and then display it again if he take another semester with different program and level.

```
    <?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM `tbl_assignedclass` where student_id ='1' ";
    $result_assign = $conn->query($query);
    while($row_assign  = $result_assign->fetch_assoc())
    {
        ?>  
        //I want to display the following data
        <div>
          statistics for studentID,<br /> 
           Semester Name - Program Name - level Name <br>
        </div>
   <?php }
  ?>
```

Comment: rtfm on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php please, there are examples there

Comment: If you're still struggling, forget about the PHP for now, and focus on the MySQL. Provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$display = '';
$dbc = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_assignedclass WHERE student_id='1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
                $id = $row['id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $email = $row['email'];
                $display .= 'ID: '.$id.' NAME: '.$name.' EMAIL: '.$email.'<br>'; 
            }
         }else{$display = 'NO RESULTS';}
echo $display;
?>
```